# How to collect data from each row in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the data of EACH row when a user has an email and put it in an array. So basically when the user clicks on the checkbox it enables the input field so they can enter an email. So far I am able to get the emails but I don't know how to get the data for each row ONLY for the users that have an email and the checkbox is still checked. For example if I select the first 2 users and enter an email I should get 2 elements in my array:

EXAMPLE:

Mike brown 3035607897 micke@gmail.com

Mary Bruns 3035607233  mary@gmail.com

**Here's my code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#checkAll").change(function() {
    $(".input_checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).each(function() {
        enable_disable_input(this);
    });
  });

  function enable_disable_input(checkbox) {
    var input_id = checkbox.id.replace('-checkbox', '-inputField');
    $("#" + input_id).prop('disabled', !checkbox.checked);
  }

  $(".input_checkbox").change(function() {
    enable_disable_input(this);
  });

  $(".input_checkbox").each(function() {
    enable_disable_input(this);
  }); 

  /* Collecting data ONLY from users that have an email */
  $("#myform").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".inputEmail").each(function(){
   if($(this).val().length > 0){
   var inputValue = $(this).val();
   console.log(inputValue);
   }
  });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id = "myform">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />Select All
  <br/>   
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="0customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td>Mike</td>
  <td>brown</td> 
  <td>3035607897</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="name" id="0customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>
<br/>

<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="1customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td>Mary</td>
  <td>Bruns</td>
  <td>3035607233</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="email" id="1customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>
<br/>

<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="2customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td>Lauren</td>
  <td>White</td>
  <td>3035634211</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="email" id="2customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>
<br/>

<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="3customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td>Tyler</td>
  <td>Steven</td>
  <td>3035236671</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="email" id="3customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>
<br/>

<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="4customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td>Carl</td>
  <td>Douglas</td>
  <td>3035227243</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="email" id="4customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>
<br/>

<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="5customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td>Peter</td>
  <td>McClure</td>
  <td>3035112239</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="email" id="5customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>  
<br/>

<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="6customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td>Liz</td>
  <td>Prems</td>
  <td>3035120075</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="email" id="6customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>
<br/>

  <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing please?? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `$.map` and `$.filter`, you can find the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). It allows you to go over your selection, `$(".inputEmail")`, and transform it by leaving it out or returning another value based on the input value.

First, give some classes to your `tds` (do this for each row with user data):

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="1customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td class="firstName">Mary</td>
  <td class="lastName">Bruns</td>
  <td class="userNumber">3035607233</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="email" id="1customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>
```

Then you can run the following point when you want to retrieve the information (in your `.submit` callback most probably):

```
var users = $("tr")
  .filter(function () { return $(this).find('.inputEmail').val() !== "" })
  .map(function () {
    var $row = $(this);
    return {
      firstName: $row.find('.firstName').text(),
      lastName: $row.find('.lastName').text(),
      number: $row.find('.userNumber').text(),
      email: $row.find('.inputEmail').val()
    }
  })
  .get();

console.log('Array containing all users with an email:');
console.log(users);
```

Comment: your answer doesn't seem to get each row and put the elements into an array?

Comment: it selects all your elements with `class="inputEmail"`, filters out the empty ones and returns the value of the other ones. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: I'm still not sure how to implement your suggestion and get the values for each row and put them into an array? Can you please share a jsfflide , codepen or something? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have edited the answer for clarity. You can put that code into your `.submit` method.

Comment: You're answer doesn't get the entire row. For example if I select the first 2 users and enter an email I should get 2 elements in my array. And these 2 elements should be each row. the first element should be Mike brown 3035607897 micke@gmail.com and the second element should be: Mary Bruns 3035607233 mary@gmail.com  Does that make sense?

Comment: I have just realized that I indeed misunderstood your question. Now the answer should be correct.

Comment: Above answer work if you put `<table>` tag around your `<tr>` tags. And put above code in `submit event`

Comment: @aesthaddicts I got it working, but the issue I have now is that when I uncheck a checkbox for any of the users (even if they already have an email) that user shouldn't be in my array. In simple words all I'm saying is that even if the user has an email BUT the checkbox is unchecked I don't want the user to be part of my array. Any ideas on how to accomplish that? by the way Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: After disabling input field in your function empty input field. Otherwise, before push in array check whether a checkbox is checked or not.
For empty field
`if(!checkbox.checked){
          $("#" + input_id).val('');
        }`

Comment: @aesthaddicts Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hi check this link for rerence check the console value http://plnkr.co/edit/3GFBckmBMomJwgMNIHrr

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "myform">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" />Select All
  <br/>  
  <table>
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="0customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td>Mike</td>
  <td>brown</td> 
  <td>3035607897</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="name" id="0customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>
<br/>

<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="1customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td>Mary</td>
  <td>Bruns</td>
  <td>3035607233</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="email" id="1customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>
<br/>

<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="2customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td>Lauren</td>
  <td>White</td>
  <td>3035634211</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="email" id="2customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>
<br/>

<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="3customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td>Tyler</td>
  <td>Steven</td>
  <td>3035236671</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="email" id="3customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>
<br/>

<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="4customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td>Carl</td>
  <td>Douglas</td>
  <td>3035227243</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="email" id="4customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>
<br/>

<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="5customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td>Peter</td>
  <td>McClure</td>
  <td>3035112239</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="email" id="5customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>  
<br/>

<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="6customer-name-checkbox" class="input_checkbox"></td>
  <td>Liz</td>
  <td>Prems</td>
  <td>3035120075</td>
  <td><input type="email" name="email" id="6customer-name-inputField" class = "inputEmail"/></td>
</tr>
<br/>
</table>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" id="send"/>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

and JS

```
// Add your javascript here
$(function() {
    $("#checkAll").change(function() {
        $(".input_checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked")).each(function() {
            enable_disable_input(this);
        });
    });

    function enable_disable_input(checkbox) {
        var input_id = checkbox.id.replace('-checkbox', '-inputField');
        $("#" + input_id).prop('disabled', !checkbox.checked);
    }

    $(".input_checkbox").change(function() {
        enable_disable_input(this);
    });

    $(".input_checkbox").each(function() {
        enable_disable_input(this);
    });

    /* Collecting data ONLY from users that have an email */
    $("#send").click(function() {
        var totalrecord = [];
        $(".inputEmail").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
                var inputValue = $(this).val();
                var $row = $(this).closest("tr"), // Finds the closest row <tr> 
                    $tds = $row.find("td"); // Finds all children <td> elements
                var abj = {};
                $.each($tds, function(index, element) {
                    console.log(index)
                    if (index == 1) {
                        abj.name = $(this).text()
                    } else if (index == 2) {
                        abj.submae = $(this).text()
                    } else if (index == 3) {
                        abj.id = $(this).text()
                    } else {
                        abj.mail = inputValue
                    }
                    console.log($(this).text())
                });
                totalrecord.push(abj)

                console.log(totalrecord)
            }
        });
    });
});
```